Why do we replace the entry to be removed in an array implementation of the ADT bag with null?

I got asked this question in an exam regarding the remove method. What would be its answer?
The remove method replaces the removed entry with null because
a. The client expects a null return value.
b. The entry could potentially be scheduled for garbage collection.
c. It is a fail-safe programming practice.
d. Otherwise it could be considered a duplicate value (I chose this answer which turned out to be incorrect).

I believe the correct answer would be "b" because the object then becomes unreachable which is one of the main tools for finding objects eligible for garbage collection

Please don't post pictures of code, post the code itself.

Do you understand why d is wrong?

please check Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

The answer is B.
When only numberOfEntries will be changed, then the object is still referenced. The Garbage collector is then not able to free the space from memory.
